# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on displaying data from arraylist

Tags: android, multithreading, indexoutofboundsexception, android-handler

I am using this piece of code for displaying image and text on footer of my app.Image and text should change after every 30 second.
Code works fine , but it randomly gives below exception and my app crashes suddenly after few mins.
Please help me on this ,
I would be grateful if there is a work around for the same task.

Exception :

```
07-24 17:14:32.812: E/AndroidRuntime(4196): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
07-24 17:14:32.812: E/AndroidRuntime(4196):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:306)
07-24 17:14:32.812: E/AndroidRuntime(4196):     at com.ht.mpnews.FragmentTabActivity$Task$1.run(FragmentTabActivity.java:491)
07-24 17:14:32.812: E/AndroidRuntime(4196):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-24 17:14:32.812: E/AndroidRuntime(4196):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-24 17:14:32.812: E/AndroidRuntime(4196):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-24 17:14:32.812: E/AndroidRuntime(4196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-24 17:14:32.812: E/AndroidRuntime(4196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 17:14:32.812: E/AndroidRuntime(4196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 17:14:32.812: E/AndroidRuntime(4196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-24 17:14:32.812: E/AndroidRuntime(4196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-24 17:14:32.812: E/AndroidRuntime(4196):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code :

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
int i=0;
class Task implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("ARrray list Size ::" ,AdsDisplay.arrListAds.size()+"");
        for (i = 0; i < AdsDisplay.arrListAds.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("For loop :::::::: " + i);

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("For loop inside runnable :::::::: " + i);

                    imageLoader.displayImage(AdsDisplay.arrListAds.get(i).ad_imageUrl, ivAdd);
                    System.out.println(AdsDisplay.arrListAds.get(i).ad_detail);

                    tvAddContent.setText(":: " + AdsDisplay.arrListAds.get(i).ad_detail);
                    tvAddContent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            Log.d("Link Clicked ::: " , AdsDisplay.arrListAds.get(i).ad_link);
                            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(AdsDisplay.arrListAds.get(i).ad_link));
                            startActivity(browserIntent);
                        }
                    });

                    if (i == (AdsDisplay.arrListAds.size())- 1) {
                        i = -1;
                        System.out.println("For loop inside :::::::: " + i);
                    }
                }
            });

            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the log of the error too?

Comment: After you do this line `i = -1;`, are you using this `i` somewhere else? Because your error is about trying to access the position = -1 in your array...

Comment: Is AdsDisplay being used in other part of your code? I think you are facing maybe, concurrency problems.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `if(i== (AdsDisplay.arrListAds.size())- 1)` to `if(i== (AdsDisplay.arrListAds.size()))`

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
 i = -1;
```

to

```
i=0;
```

2nd time on wards your for loop start with i=-1.

Comment: if I put i=0 ; I didnt get the text of index 0 , it repeat the text of index 1 after every 30 seconds , means I get 0 , 1 ,1,1,1,..